# NHibernate is unable to resolve classes in a dynamically loaded assembly loaded from a subdirectory

Tags: nhibernate, .net-core, nhibernate-mapping

//Formatting is not properly done.

Using nopcommerce plugins written in nhibernate and .net core, each plugins contains its own entities directory, but when NHibernate configuration fails

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure(CommonHelper.MapPath("~/App_Data/db/defauls.config"));
// error here
cfg.AddAssembly("plugins assembly name");
```

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '***plugins assembly name***' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, string codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, ref StackCrawlMark stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks)
MappingException: persistent class "***plugins assembly name***.Entities.class name, ***plugins assembly name*** not found

NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder.ClassForFullNameChecked(string fullName, string errorMessage)
MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: ***plugins assembly name***.Entities.class name.hbm.xml

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
```

Comment: If the cfg or not Embedded resource hbm.xml file in the plugin is not error occurred, i think the problem is not with NHibernate, it is with the way i load assemblies but do not know how to solve

Comment: Please pass assembly name with your plugin namespace.
If your plugin namespace is Nop.Plugin.Misc.Name and DLL assembly name is MyExample.Core.DLL

Than you have to pass `Nop.Plugin.Misc.Name.MyExample.Core`

This will work for add assembly in plugin.

Comment: namespace **Plugin.Shop.Entities**, assembly **Plugin.Shop** in **Plugin.Shop.Entities** i have class **Amounts.cs** and file **Amounts.hbm.xml**

Comment: than pass in  Plugin.Shop.Entities.Plugin.Shop  assembly name

Comment: You can add DLL in plugin root folder and give reference from there

Comment: My problem is that nhibernate can not load `Plugin.Shop` when I declare `cfg.AddAssembly ("Plugin.Shop");`  `Plugin.Shop` is loaded as a plugins

Comment: You have to give reference of that DLL and make it false to Copy Output folder

Comment: Can you give me an example not to solve this problem

Comment: Please check below answer

Answer (score 0):

Assume Plugin.Shop.dll is placed in root folder of plugin Plugin.Shop.Entities folder. 
From property select content type as Embedded Resource 
and give reference of this DLL and from property set it False to copy out folder.

This is EmbeddedAssembly.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Plugin.Shop.Entities
{
    public class EmbeddedAssembly
    {
        // Version 1.0

        static Dictionary<string, Assembly> dic = null;

        public static void Load(string embeddedResource, string fileName)
        {
            if (dic == null)
                dic = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

            byte[] ba = null;
            Assembly asm = null;
            Assembly curAsm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            using (Stream stm = curAsm.GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedResource))
            {
                // Either the file is not existed or it is not mark as embedded resource
                if (stm == null)
                    throw new Exception(embeddedResource + " is not found in Embedded Resources.");

                // Get byte[] from the file from embedded resource
                ba = new byte[(int)stm.Length];
                stm.Read(ba, 0, (int)stm.Length);
                try
                {
                    asm = Assembly.Load(ba);

                    // Add the assembly/dll into dictionary
                    dic.Add(asm.FullName, asm);
                    return;
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Purposely do nothing
                    // Unmanaged dll or assembly cannot be loaded directly from byte[]
                    // Let the process fall through for next part
                }
            }

            bool fileOk = false;
            string tempFile = "";

            using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                string fileHash = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(ba)).Replace("-", string.Empty); ;

                tempFile = Path.GetTempPath() + fileName;

                if (File.Exists(tempFile))
                {
                    byte[] bb = File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile);
                    string fileHash2 = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(bb)).Replace("-", string.Empty);

                    if (fileHash == fileHash2)
                    {
                        fileOk = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fileOk = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    fileOk = false;
                }
            }

            if (!fileOk)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, ba);
            }

            asm = Assembly.LoadFile(tempFile);

            dic.Add(asm.FullName, asm);
        }

        public static Assembly Get(string assemblyFullName)
        {
            if (dic == null || dic.Count == 0)
                return null;

            if (dic.ContainsKey(assemblyFullName))
                return dic[assemblyFullName];

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is Dependency Register File

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;
using Nop.Core.Configuration;
using Nop.Core.Data;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure.DependencyManagement;
using Nop.Data;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Plugin.Shop.Entities.Infrastructure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency registrar
    /// </summary>
    public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
    {       
        public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder, NopConfig config)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<NameService>().As<INameService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            string codeDll = "Plugin.Shop.Entities.Plugin.Shop.dll";
            EmbeddedAssembly.Load(codeDll, "Plugin.Shop.dll");

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
        }

        private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            return EmbeddedAssembly.Get(args.Name);
        }

        public int Order
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoyceK - Hope this is work and Mark this post as answer so it'll help to community